# get html elements of <tr>....</tr> by creating a httpwebrequest in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to extract some html elements from the "tablerow" contents of a html code and create a automated application.Can httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse help me doing that ? if yes then 
could any one show me the sample of doing that...Thanking you in advance

Comment: Google how to use HttpWebRequest, and finally when you have the source code of the responded html page, extract your valuable information with regular expressions, just as you would interpret normal text.

Answer (score 0):

I would go get HtmlAgilityPack from nuget. WebClient is easier, but HttpWebRequest is more powerful and allows for more control. Regex can work, but is generally a pain. If you think this document will be well enough formatted a quick XPath to the elements in question is usually much easier and cleaner, so try something like this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
//var html = client.DownloadString("YOURURL");
var html = "<html><body><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></body></html>";
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/table");

Console.WriteLine(nodes[0].InnerHtml);
Console.ReadLine();
```